# How to convert Bearing to direction?

Tags: java, android, compass, bearing

Someone knows how an easy way to convert Bearing (0° to -180° and 0° to 180°) to Compass Direction (0° to 360°)? I searched for a Location method or a user function but...

Comment: Add 180 to the bearing?

Comment: No, -90° must be equal to 270°.

Comment: You don't need a Location method. It's basic arithmetic.

Comment: `direction = (bearing >= 0) ? bearing : 360 + bearing;`

Comment: thank you [Elliot Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch). I got a mind's blackout here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as [Ellion Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) sugested above.